# Show photos stored in device on a nativescript android app

Tags: javascript, android, nativescript

I'm making an android app with nativescript, I'm using **couchbase** as database and i need to store a reference to photos taken with the **camera-module** for thumbnails of items, and display those photos inside a ***ListView***.
I've searched multiple tutorials about using the camera module and displaying the image using **ImageSource** class, and they work when i use [fromAsset](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_image_source_.imagesource.html#fromasset) passing the object returned by **cameraModule.takePicture**, but not when i use [fromFile](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_image_source_.imagesource.html#fromfile) passing the path in the same object (*picture.android* property), as it seems it only works within the application folder.

```
cameraModule.takePicture().then((picture) => {

    let myImage = page.getViewById("image-test");
    let source = new imageSource.ImageSource();

    // This works
    source.fromAsset(picture).then(source => {
        myImage.imageSource = source;
    });

    // This doesn't
    source.fromFile(picture.android).then(source => {
        myImage.imageSource = source;
    });

});
```

What would be the best way to store the reference and recreate the imageSource? Can i store the whole *imageAsset* object in couchbase? Or what would be the right way to create an imageSource whit that path?

Answer (score 0):

Well i don't know what i was doing wrong, it seems to work fine with the path returned in the picture object.
The only thing i changed was the asynchronous method ***fromFile*** for the synchronous one ***loadFromFile***, but maybe my mistake was somewhere else.